# Third Part Device: Get 4G on the "Uncarrier" via Root Permissions

Tags: root-access, 4g

I have a third part device. BLU STUDIO 5.5. I think my carrier (T-Mobile, a.k.a "The Uncarrier") said that this phone is originally an AT&T or Sprint phone, I don't remember. Point is, that it's a 4G capable phone. Not LTE, just 4G. I'm only getting Edge on my device right now. I have followed the APN Settings but no cigar, it was already set correctly.

My device is rooted. Is there any way to get 4G on it?

Comment: [GSM Arena](http://www.gsmarena.com/blu_studio_5_5-5761.php) shows two variants (D610a and D610i), [Phone Arena](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/BLU-Studio-5.5_id8309) only has one. None supports T-Mobile's main 4G frequency bands (AWS), though the D610a might be able to get on their older (slower) PCS bands if they are in-use in your area. The answer is probably "no" either way, though, since T-Mobile has been refarming the PCS for other things, AFAIK.

Comment: That's a bummer, I got this phone being excited. Aside from having WiFi in most places anyway, I still wanted there to be 4G. It's a shame. Not even other ROMS can access different types of networks? I'd assume it's hardware-related, right?